# Invariant type error when using Jest mount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, frontend, web-development-server

So I have a React Class lets call it A. I'm running a jest test on it, but I keep getting an

`Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

In the React Class I'm doing : 
`export class A extends Component ..`

In the jest test file I'm doing :
`import { A } from './A.js'`

when I run :
`const wrapper = mount(<A />)`

I get the error above. I'm running on a jsdom environment for jest. I'm kind of at a loss why this wouldn't work. I've read that some people export as default, but I don't see why doing a proper name import shouldn't work. Does anyone have any ideas what could be the issue?

real code : 
jest file :

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import { A } from '../A';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/**
 * Test Suite
 */
describe('A test', () => {
 it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
   const wrapper = mount(<A />);
 })
})
```

react class :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class A extends Component {
...
}
```

jest config :

```
module.exports = {
    clearMocks: true,

    // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
    coverageDirectory: 'coverage',

    // The test environment that will be used for testing
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testURL: 'http://localhost/',

    // Directory to search for tests
    roots: ['src/'],

    // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
    testMatch: [
        '**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)',
        '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'
    ],

    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/'
    ],

    snapshotSerializers: [
        'enzyme-to-json/serializer'
    ]
};
```

Comment: Can you share the actual code? Your theoretical example should work but I suspect your code may have an issue. Please share a [mcve]

Comment: @LMulvey I've updated with real code

Answer (score 1):

That is the error that you get when you attempt to render an `Object` as a `Component`.

Here is an example:

A.js

```
import * as React from 'react';

const AnObject = {};  // <= NOT a component

export class A extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<AnObject/>);  // <= Attempt to render an object as a component
  }
}
```

A.test.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { A } from './A';

test('A', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<A/>);  // <= Fails with "Invariant Violation: Element type...
});
```

...which gives the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `A`.

```
  5 | 
  6 | test('A', () => {
> 7 |   const wrapper = mount(<A/>);
    |                   ^
  8 | });
  9 |
```

---

You'll want to check `A` at the point of the test and make sure it is actually your component.

Then work backwards and make sure everything rendered as a component by `A` is actually a component (and so on) until you find the non-component that is being used as a component.

Answer (score 0):

## LayoutGroup  is not a default export

You cannot call `LayoutGroup` via  `import { A } from '../A';` it is not exported with default so you cannot rename it as a named import.

To do something like this change

`import { A } from './A.js'`

to

`import A from './A.js'`

and

`export class LayoutGroup extends Component {`

to

`export default class LayoutGroup extends Component {`

Comment: my apologies, that was a typo on my end. I replaced all instances of LayoutGroup with A. Missed that one.